# How could I add a header element to md-virtual-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular 1.x, with Angular Material.

What I'd like to do is create an `md-virtual-repeat-container`, where the first element is a special element, different to all the rest, with a much larger height.

I can place the first element above the virtual repeat container, but unfortunately it is no longer part of the same scroll element, which is the intended result.

Is it possible to accomplish this? What sort of technique should I use? I don't mind writing a directive, or whatever I need to do, but I do need some direction to get started.